# Could not GET api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repository. when building my react-native project for android

Tags: android, react-native, bitbucket-api

I got an old running project that when built shows dependency error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-mqtt-iot'.
  >   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-mqtt-iot:_debugPublishCopy'.
  >   Could not resolve co.ibhubs.ibchat:ibchat:0.0.1.
  >          Required by:
  >              project :react-native-mqtt-iot
  >   Could not resolve co.ibhubs.ibchat:ibchat:0.0.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/mumsnbabies/maven_awsiot/raw/releases/co/ibhubs/ibchat/ibchat/0.0.1/ibchat-0.0.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/mumsnbabies/maven_awsiot/raw/releases/co/ibhubs/ibchat/ibchat/0.0.1/ibchat-0.0.1.pom'. Received status code 410 from server: Gone
  >   Could not resolve co.ibhubs.ibchat:ibchat:0.0.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/mumsnbabies/maven_ibchat/raw/releases/co/ibhubs/ibchat/ibchat/0.0.1/ibchat-0.0.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/mumsnbabies/maven_ibchat/raw/releases/co/ibhubs/ibchat/ibchat/0.0.1/ibchat-0.0.1.pom'. Received status code 410 from server: Gone

Is it because of change of api version from 1.0 to 2.0? If so how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I got the solution to fix.
In my case i change the url from https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/mumsnbabies/maven_awsiot/raw/releases/co/ibhubs/ibchat/ibchat/0.0.1/ibchat-0.0.1.pom

to

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/mumsnbabies/maven_awsiot/src/releases/co/ibhubs/ibchat/ibchat/0.0.1/ibchat-0.0.1.pom

And adding the following lines of code before the url:

```
authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
```